# How do I make JavaFX MediaView stretch media to fill parent container?

Tags: java, javafx, media

I'm trying to make my video's dimensions stretch automatically and fill the MediaView and maintain the original aspect ratio of the video. Basically, I want my MediaPlayer to fit the parent container on resize etc. like pretty much all video players do.

If anyone could shed some light on how to achieve this that would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of stretching to the containing Scene and the scene is set by the Dimension "size":

```
final MediaPlayer videoPlayer = new MediaPlayer(
    new Media(new File(videoPath).toURI().toString()));
MediaView mv = new MediaView(videoPlayer);
DoubleProperty mvw = mv.fitWidthProperty();
DoubleProperty mvh = mv.fitHeightProperty();
mvw.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
mvh.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));
mv.setPreserveRatio(true);

setScene(new Scene(new Group(mv), size.getWidth(), size.getHeight()));
```

Comment: Essentially just bind fitWidth/fitHeight property to its parent (in kbickar case that's the scene).


  mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(parent.widthProperty());
  mediaView.fitHeightProperty().bind(parent.heightProperty());

Answer (score 7):

A more declarative way in a ".fxml" file would be:

```
...
<Pane fx:id="mediaViewPane">
  <children>
     <MediaView fx:id="videoView" fitHeight="${mediaViewPane.height}" fitWidth="${mediaViewPane.width}" layoutX="1.0" />
  </children>
</Pane>
...
```

You can use the "${...}" syntax for any attribute in your ".fxml" for Expression Binding.
If you want to call a UI element you have to provide a "fx:id". For example in this case it's fx:id="mediaViewPane".

So you don't have to care about the UI stuff in your code.
For me it's a little bit cleaner.

Comment: This seems to work for sizes bigger than the video itself. The pane doesn't seem to shrink bellow the size of the video.

Comment: Hmm ok. I cant reproduce your behaviour. When I try the above snippet my MediaView can shrink or grow with the size of e.g. the Scene.
Anyway this answer was only intended to show a way to do the code stuff in fxml ;)

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled with this but I did this

```
mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
mediaView.fitHeightproperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
```

and I worked for me. The `mediaView` played at the same size as the stage / window. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized no-one answered this so I'll answer it.

Just set the media player fitWidthProperty to that of the MediaView so:

```
player.fitWidthProperty().bind(mediaView.widthProperty());
```

and the same for the height (if you wanted) and also preserveRatio and stuff.

Comment: This code seems wrong. MediaPlayer doesn't have that property. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html