# How do I make JavaFX MediaView stretch and shrink media to fill/fit parent container?

Tags: java, javafx, mediaview

How do  I make JavaFX MediaView stretch **and shrink** media to fill/fit parent container?

There's already a question here:

[How do I make JavaFX MediaView stretch media to fill parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090378/how-do-i-make-javafx-mediaview-stretch-media-to-fill-parent-container)

and the solution with this code:

```
<Pane fx:id="mediaViewPane">
  <children>
     <MediaView fx:id="videoView" fitHeight="${mediaViewPane.height}" fitWidth="${mediaViewPane.width}" layoutX="1.0" />
  </children>
</Pane>
```

works for making the video bigger to fill the container, but it doesn't allow the container to be smaller than the size of the video, so, it doesn't shrink, it just starts hiding controls as they fall outside the scene.

Any ideas how to stretch but also shrink the MediaView to fit?

Comment: Try adding `managed="false"` to the `<MediaView>` element. This should make the `Pane` behave as if it was empty. You may need to set the preferred size of the `Pane` to suit your needs...

Comment: @fabian: that seems to help. Now it resizes past the size of the video. The problem is that if it's not managed, it can be centered by the parent, as one would expect. I guess this approach would require adding code to center it in the parent.

Comment: Is it possible to use `mediaView.setScaleX/Y()` though that would require handling size changes your self and calculating the appropriate scaling factor. Got the thought from this SO question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161931/how-to-scale-and-set-coordinates-of-mediaview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this, although I'm not super confident about this being the best approach. First, as fabian pointed out, I need to set the `MediaView` as not managed so that the parent `Pane` can be resized to any size without the `MediaView` constraining it:

```
<Pane fx:id="mediaViewPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0">
    <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" StackPane.alignment="CENTER" managed="false"/>
</Pane>
```

Then, on a rezise event, I resize the `MediaView` to fit in the parent, then get the actual size of the video and offset it to center:

```
InvalidationListener resizeMediaView = observable -> {
    mediaView.setFitWidth(mediaViewPane.getWidth());
    mediaView.setFitHeight(mediaViewPane.getHeight());

    // After setting a big fit width and height, the layout bounds match the video size. Not sure why and this feels fragile.
    Bounds actualVideoSize = mediaView.getLayoutBounds();
    mediaView.setX((mediaView.getWidth() - actualVideoSize.getWidth()) / 2);
    mediaView.setY((mediaView.getHeight() - actualVideoSize.getHeight()) / 2);
};
mediaViewPane.heightProperty().addListener(resizeMediaView);
mediaViewPane.widthProperty().addListener(resizeMediaView);
```