# Making a video (media) player in JavaFX take as much space as possible but no more

Tags: java, javafx

I previously asked this question: [How do I make JavaFX MediaView stretch and shrink media to fill/fit parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095272/how-do-i-make-javafx-mediaview-stretch-and-shrink-media-to-fill-fit-parent-conta) about making a JavaFX media player expand to fill the parent. Unfortunately, that hack with a pane around the video pushes the controllers far away from the video:

[image]

The colors are there just to understand how the layout is acting. The video player is composed of this FXML:

```
<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
    <Pane fx:id="mediaViewPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0"
          minWidth="0.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"  style="-fx-background-color: green;">
        <MediaView fx:id="tutorialPlayer" managed="false" />
    </Pane>
    <Slider fx:id="timeSlider" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
        </VBox.margin>
    </Slider>
    <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: magenta;" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES">
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
        </padding>
        <Button fx:id="playButton" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#play">
            <graphic>
                <FontIcon iconLiteral="fas-play" iconSize="25" />
            </graphic>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="pauseButton" managed="false" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pause" visible="false">
            <graphic>
                <FontIcon iconLiteral="fas-pause" iconSize="25" />
            </graphic>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="restartButton" disable="true" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#restart">
            <graphic>
                <FontIcon iconLiteral="fas-retweet" iconSize="25" />
            </graphic>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="muteButton" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mute">
            <graphic>
                <FontIcon iconLiteral="fas-volume-up" iconSize="25" />
            </graphic>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="unmuteButton" managed="false" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#unmute" visible="false">
            <graphic>
                <FontIcon iconLiteral="fas-volume-off" iconSize="25" />
            </graphic>
        </Button>
        <Slider fx:id="volumeSlider" blockIncrement="0.1" max="1.0" value="1.0" />
    </HBox>
    <HBox.margin>
        <Insets />
    </HBox.margin>
    <opaqueInsets>
        <Insets />
    </opaqueInsets>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
</VBox>
```

While the hacky code to resize is this:

```
    // Resize the video to fit and fill the allocated space. Why isn't this the default?????
    InvalidationListener resizeTutorialPlayer = observable -> {
        tutorialPlayer.setFitWidth(mediaViewPane.getWidth());
        tutorialPlayer.setFitHeight(mediaViewPane.getHeight());

        Bounds actualVideoSize = tutorialPlayer.getLayoutBounds(); // After setting a big fit width and height, the layout bounds match the video size. Not sure why and this feels fragile.
        tutorialPlayer.setX((mediaViewPane.getWidth() - actualVideoSize.getWidth()) / 2);
        tutorialPlayer.setY((mediaViewPane.getHeight() - actualVideoSize.getHeight()) / 2);
    };
    mediaViewPane.heightProperty().addListener(resizeTutorialPlayer);
    mediaViewPane.widthProperty().addListener(resizeTutorialPlayer);
```

Any ideas how to have the same as big as possible and centered while respecting the aspect ratio functionality but keeping the controllers for the video just next to the video?

Comment: Add your `FXML` imports. I am guessing you are using some third party library? I can't get it to load in `SceneBuilder`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ikonli. If you remove the images in the buttons it'll work. I can add more details when I get home but that's the faster way for you to load it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make this work with your current strategy by wrapping the controls and media view in another pane (`VBox`?), then subtracting the height of the controls when you set the media view's `fitHeight` property. Then just configure that pane so it centers everything.

To be honest, though, I try to avoid using bindings and listeners to manage layout. Sometimes it's inevitable, but once you reach a certain critical point it's probably better to define a custom layout by subclassing `Pane`. The strategy I outlined above exceeds that critical point, in my judgement (your mileage may vary, of course).

So I'd define a layout pane specifically to manage this. It's not too bad; just override the various `computeXXWidth/Height()` methods and the `layoutChildren()` method:

```
package mediaviewlayout;
import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

public class MediaViewLayout extends Pane {

    private final MediaView mediaView ;
    private final Node content ;

    private static final double SPACING = 5 ; // can make this configurable if needed...

    public MediaViewLayout(
            @NamedArg("mediaView") MediaView mediaView,
            @NamedArg("content") Node content) {

        this.mediaView = mediaView ;
        this.content = content ;

        this.getChildren().addAll(mediaView, content);
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMinWidth(double height) {
        return Math.max(mediaView.minWidth(height), content.minWidth(height));
    }

    @Override
    public double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return Math.max(mediaView.prefWidth(height), content.prefWidth(height));
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMaxWidth(double height) {
        return Math.min(mediaView.maxWidth(height), content.maxWidth(height));
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMinHeight(double width) {
        return mediaView.minHeight(width) + content.minHeight(width) + SPACING ;
    }

    @Override
    public double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return mediaView.prefHeight(width) + content.prefHeight(width) + SPACING ;
    }

    @Override
    public double computeMaxHeight(double width) {
        return mediaView.maxHeight(width) + content.minHeight(width) + SPACING ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double width = getWidth();
        double height = getHeight();
        double contentHeight = content.prefHeight(-1);
        double availableHeight = height - SPACING - contentHeight ;
        mediaView.setFitWidth(width);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(availableHeight);
        Bounds actualMediaBounds = mediaView.getBoundsInLocal();
        double totalUsedHeight = actualMediaBounds.getHeight() + SPACING + contentHeight ;

        double mediaX = (width - actualMediaBounds.getWidth()) / 2 ;
        double mediaY = (height - totalUsedHeight) / 2;
        mediaView.relocate(mediaX, mediaY);

        content.resizeRelocate(0, mediaY+actualMediaBounds.getHeight()+SPACING, width, contentHeight);

    }
}
```

This always places the `content` below the media view. You could introduce additional properties such as an `ObjectProperty<Side>` if you wanted to make this more configurable and resuable.

You can then test this out either in Java:

```
package mediaviewlayout;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MediaViewTest extends Application {

    private static final String MEDIA_URL = "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView();
        mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(MEDIA_URL));
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

        VBox controls = new VBox(5);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Slider slider = new Slider();

        controls.getChildren().add(slider);

        Button play = new Button("Play");


        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, play, new Button("Restart"), new Button("Volume"), new Slider());
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        controls.getChildren().add(buttons);

        MediaViewLayout layout = new MediaViewLayout(mediaView, controls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

or in FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import mediaviewlayout.MediaViewLayout?>

<?import javafx.scene.media.Media?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<MediaViewLayout xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" style="-fx-background-color: green;">
    <mediaView>
       <MediaView>
           <mediaPlayer>
               <MediaPlayer autoPlay="true">
                   <media>
                       <Media source="http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv"/>
                   </media>
               </MediaPlayer>
           </mediaPlayer>
       </MediaView>
    </mediaView>
    <content>
       <VBox spacing="5" style="-fx-background-color: red;">
           <Slider/>
           <HBox spacing="5" alignment="TOP_CENTER" style="-fx-background-color: magenta;">
               <Button text="Play"/>
               <Button text="Restart"/>
               <Button text="Volume"/>
               <Slider/>
           </HBox>
       </VBox>
    </content>
</MediaViewLayout>
```

with

```
package mediaviewlayout;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MediaViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        MediaViewLayout layout = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MediaViewLayoutTest.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Screenshot from FXML version:

[image]

Comment: As usual, @James_D, absolutely amazing!